# SEO question in regards to current way of loading my pages

Tags: seo, google, php, ajax

I'm trying to implement SEO-friendly (or at least indexable) way of dynamically displaying categories; first by allowing user to use javascript to dynamically load pages via ajax (.load) and secondly via php upon refresh (include, by means of current $_GET).

This is how I have the category tree implemented:
[image] 

Each of the menu entries has a href with id, which points to index.php?category=_, which does allow usage of the tree without javascript, to some extent. If javascript is indeed enabled, I load the page (on the right) with ajax.

My question is: **if I'm using the current setup, will google indeed index my pages (for example: index.php?category=2)**? Thanks in advance!